# How can I create a sitemap for 2000 products powered by a single php page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, googlebot, 404, crawl-errors

Usually I generate sitemaps using `www.xml-sitemaps.com` and the limit is 500 pages. My website has barely 30, but I have a lot of products in my database, so the page `product.php` becomes `product.php?id=xx` for each product. When I try to create the sitemap, it also calculates all the duplicate pages for `product.php` and it creates as many duplicates as are the products in my database, more than 2000, so when it reaches 500 it stops and the sitemap is incomplete.

How can I prevent this and only take in consideration once the file `product.php` and not as many times as the IDs I have?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.  If you have two unrelated questions, it makes sense to ask them separetly.   I have edited your post to remove one of the two questions.  If you wish to get an answer to the removed question, please use the "ask question" link at the top of the page and ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

First make separate webpages for your each products which will help you lot from SEO point of view. And for creating XML sitemap for more the 500 pages use software like Xenu, Screamfrogseo which are one of the popular software for SEO's from long time.

Comment: Hi and thank you. What do you mean by ' create webpages for each product ' ? The product.php page gets the $_GET['id'] and displays the product associated with that ID

Comment: As far as search engines are concerned, each URL with a different set of parameters is a different page.  So despite the fact that all your products are served by the same script, you already have a "page" for each product.